# Joining records in mongodb with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, asynchronous, sails.js

I'm using [sails](http://sailsjs.org/) in my project. Which I have a two models, user and permission.

`user`

```
{
     c_name: 'string',
     e_name: 'string'
}
```

`permission`

```
user: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    unique: true
},

permissions: {
    type: 'array'
}
```

I would want to find all users with their corresponding permissions using their `user.id`. However since I'm using mongodb, instead of a relational database, I cannot do join with SQL. Therefore, here are the steps I was thinking:

1. get all users
2. loop through the users
3. for each user find their permission
4. add the permission to the user
5. output the users array.

Below is my method of achieving it.

I'm using [node.async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to queue my calls.

`UserController.js`

```
var async = require('async'); // using node.async

module.exports = {
    find: function (req, res){
        async.auto({
        getUsers: function(callback){
            User.find().done(function(err, users){
                callback(err, users);
            });
        },
        getPermission: ['getUsers', function(callback, users){
            async.each(users.getUsers, function (user, cb){
                Permission.findOne({'user': user.id}).done(function (err, permission){
                    if (permission)
                        user.permissions = permission.permissions;
                    cb();
                });
            }, function(err){
                callback(users);
            });
        }]
    }, function(err, results) {
         // console.log(results);
        res.send(results.getUsers);
    });
   }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better solution please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices here to make your code more efficient: either upgrade to Sails v0.10 if you haven't already, and use the built-in associations functionality, or use embedded documents in Mongo.  If you go with option one, your models would looks something like:

**User attributes**:

```
{
    c_name: 'string',
    e_name: 'string',
    permissions: {
        collection: 'permission',
        via: 'user'
    }
}
```

**Permission attributes:**

```
{
    permission: 'string', // or whatever
    user: {
        model: 'user'
    }
}
```

Then you can add permissions to a user instance with `myUser.permissions.add(permissionId)` followed by `myUser.save(function(err, savedUser){...})`, or by creating / updating a `permission` instance with its `user` attribute set to a user ID.  To retrieve users with their permissions, you would do `User.find(criteria).populate('permissions').exec(...)`.

You can install Sails v0.10 with `npm install sails@beta`.  The docs are at http://beta.sailsjs.org, although they are subject to change.

To use embedded documents in Mongo with Sails, simply merge your existing `permission` model into `user` by adding a `permissions: 'array'` attribute to the `User.js`.  Considering that the way you have it set up now, each User instance would have at most one linked Permission instance, there's really no reason to have them as two separate models.  The only real benefit to option one is the ability to query permissions seperate from users, i.e. to ask questions like "which users have so-and-so permission" or "how many users have a permission above level x"?  If those questions aren't relevant in your app, there's no reason to keep `permission` as a separate model.

Comment: This is really useful!!! Thank you very much for your information! Just curious do you know when will sails 0.10 be an official release?